# How retrive user name from user_id in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

hellow i want to show 10 persons who has deposited amount in last24 hours . i am able to show there user_id and amount but i want users name  instead of user_id.

i have no name colum  in $funds it is in users
i have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="text-center"><h4 class="text-success">Last 10 Investors</h4></div>
    <table class="table text-white" >
        <tbody>
            @foreach( \App\Fund::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get() as $fund)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td>{{ $fund->user_id }}</td>
                <td class="text-center text-warning">{{ $fund->total }}</td>
                <td class="text-right"><img src="https://adsok.com/img/btc.png" alt="Bitcoin"> <i><b>bitcoin</b></i><br></td><br>
            </tr>@endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: try with `{{ $fund->user_name }}`.

Comment: i have no name  columin in $funds it is in users

Comment: Then you have join the user table in this query to get the name.

Comment: please how i can do it

Comment: Use relations to your `Fund` model to relate with `User` model
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: didn't got it. please make sample

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a relation from your Fund Model to the User Model

In your Fund model,

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id'); 
}
```

and you could access the User that belongs to the fund as

```
$fund->user->{your-username-field}
```

OR if you don't want to set up a relationship and fetch the username, you could do so by

```
$user = \App\User::find($fund->user_id);
if (! empty($user)) {
    $user_name = $user->user_name; // or whatever the username field is
}
```

Comment: @Waqar Ali this the best solution.

Comment: @Rafee It will be considered 2 queries instead of one .Now let waqar decide that he would require 2 queries or just a single query to accomplish that task. :)

Comment: once it worked well but now  it is giving error woops some thing went wrong wheni add $fund->$user->name

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fund extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'funds';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'payment_type',
        'transaction_id',
        'amount',
        'rate',
        'charge',
        'total',
    ];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id'); 
}
}

Comment: What exactly is the error? Apart from `Woops something went wrong`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
@foreach( \App\Fund::select("*")->with('users')->where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get()->toArray() as $fund)
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>{{ $fund['user']['user_name'] }}</td>
       <td class="text-center text-warning">{{ $fund->total }}</td>
      <td class="text-right"><img src="https://adsok.com/img/btc.png" alt="Bitcoin"> <i><b>bitcoin</b></i><br></td><br>
    </tr>@endforeach
```

Comment: Here I am assuming that you have set up the relationship in the modals.

Comment: That will be in the user table

Comment: i have no idea about it .  please help

Comment: @KetanSolanki `$fund` is a model not an array. It will throw error.

Comment: @Rafee `$fund` in as allias which contains the array ,Please check my answer.

Comment: Oops, my bad. didnt noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

so you have to models: "Fund" and "User".
you should connect them with Laravel's Relationships:
add this method to "User" model:

```
public function funds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fund', 'user_id');
}
```

then in "Fund" model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

now you can access user's name from funds:
i suggest you to retrive your datas in controller, not views:

```
public function index()
{
    $funds = Fund::with('user')->
        where('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->
            subHours(24))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
    return view('viewName', ['funds' => $funds]);
}
```

then in view:

```
@foreach ($funds as $fund)
    {{ $fund->user->name }}
@endforeach
```